# Error model result when some of value is missing

Tags: pmml

I have error of pmml(NYOKA) model scoring by **pypmml** library in Python

Result is missing when some of value of columns is missing an dgive result onlye when not missing values.

Model: lgbm, which score even of value is missing

Comment: Paste your model for clarity.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.